# Exception generated by PropertyMappingFactory class with trying to the first element of an array with twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig, vichuploaderbundle

I have a `Motors` entity having an **OneToMany** relation with the `File` entity. Uploading files and linking them is done with VichUploaderBundle.

My objective is giving a simple overview of a `Motors` object by displaying just the first image of that object. Since, I am using twig for displaying my object, I used the `first` filter of twig as follows:

```
{{ vich_uploader_asset(motors.files|first, 'motors_files') }}
```

This was not successful. The error I got is:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Impossible to determine the class name. Either specify it explicitly or give an object") in MinnAdsBundle:Motors:index.html.twig at line 75**

It seems that exception is generated by that class [PropertyMappingFactory.php](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Mapping/PropertyMappingFactory.php,.).

I also tried this:

```
{%for f in motors.files|first %}
    {{ vich_uploader_asset(f, 'motors_files') }}<br>
{%endfor%}
```

**But, there is nothing rendered. There is also no error generated!!!** This is strange since applying the filters `first` and 'length' returns the expected value (1 or 0):

```
{{motors.files|first|length}} {#always return the expected value#}
```

---

I did even more checks as seen below but without success! So, could you help with that issue?

Thanks!

```
{# the length of the array#}
{{motors.files|length}} {# tells me that there is 3 files! (worked perfectly)#}

{# Retrieving all the links of these file (worked perfectly)#}
{%for f in motors.files%}
    {{ vich_uploader_asset(f, 'motors_files') }}<br>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Maybe you have PersistentCollection here, that isn't initialized or so.. Try `{{ vich_uploader_asset(motors.files.first, 'motors_files') }}`

Comment: Still have the same exception: **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Impossible to determine the class name. Either specify it explicitly or give an object") in MinnAdsBundle:Motors:index.html.twig at line 84.**

Comment: the bundle isn't able to retrieve the classname of the object returned by `motors.files|first`. This is the problem!!! @Ziumin

Comment: could you make `{{ dump(motors.files|first) }}`?

Comment: good idea! I wiil be to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended the problem by an if condition in the loop:

```
{%for f in motors.files%}
    {%if loop.index == 1%}
        src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(f, 'motors_files')}}"
   {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
```

There is a problem with the `VichUploaderBundle` when dealing with the filter `first`.